# MySQL stored procedure PHP JSON response

Tags: php, mysql, json, stored-procedures

We have been building mobile applications with PHP playing the service layer interacting with  a MySQL database.I was thinking of going a little further to implement stored procedures in MySQL database to perform the task of fetching data.There by , removing any SQL from the PHP code.

I did check online for related information , but could not find much.Following are some of my concerns :

- Can MySQL stored procedures return a user defined data type like a list? (Based on what I could search and find out , seems like these are accepted only as IN parameters).

  - Would returning the whole JSON formatted string (Yes , I know this would be little heavy) , have a negative impact on performance?

I am relatively new to PHP , MySQL and mobile application development as well.Based on my past experience with Oracle PL/SQL , I assume writing the queries within the database would really be advantageous.

Comment: As far as i know, MySQL uses 'functions' to "return" things, and it only returns valid MySQL data types, according to the documentation.
I think, choosing between returning a JSON formatted string or formatting it outside, depends on how busy your server is going to be.
I may suggest you to use PostgreSQL as well, which is more flexible and faster than MySQL, as far as i experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mehmet ! In this case I would like to explore return in a character type which would contain the whole result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored functions return a single scalar value, which could represent whatever it needs to, to your application, and a stored procedure can return values via its `OUT` parameters, but, more interesting and useful to me is the fact that **a procedure can return one or more result sets to the client**, using one or more unbounded `SELECT` statements in the procedure body.  An unbounded `SELECT` is a `SELECT` that is not nested inside a subquery, not part of a cursor declaration, and not part of a `SELECT ... INTO` statement:

> MySQL supports a very useful extension that enables the use of regular `SELECT` statements (that is, without using cursors or local variables) inside a stored procedure. The result set of such a query is simply sent directly to the client. Multiple `SELECT` statements generate multiple result sets, so the client must use a MySQL client library that supports multiple result sets.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines-syntax.html (supported in all 5.x releases)</sup>

To your client, these look just like what you'd see if you had issued a `SELECT` query... so you could return a table of elements that your application could wrap up in JSON.

Or... there is also a 3rd party library of MySQL user-defined functions (server extensions, written in C/C++, not to be confused with stored functions) that can generate JSON on the server.

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json

Would I try this?  Yes, I would try this.  Is assembling JSON objects inside the database server the most efficient or best way of handling it?  That's certainly debatable, but we could contemplate and debate the theoretical aspects of this all day long and not be much closer to a solution than when we started.

Comment: Really appreciate your response Michael ! I would like to go a little further to understand the return type possible , like if I can return a data type like an array rather than returning a varchar. Also , hope what you meant while saying "a procedure can return one or more result sets to the client" is through fetching the results "into" a variable and returning the same as parameters. Like , if we are to return a list of people and another of cities , these would become different out parameters. please correct me if I am wrong.Thanks.!

Comment: It's better than that.  You can return multiple *result sets* -- actual proper sets of rows and columns that look identical to what you can generate using a series of `SELECT` statements -- to the client from a stored procedure.  I will add a specific example to my answer later today.